# how to use session in hyper link selection

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a hyperlink in my web page, the link should be work if the user is logged in if not it should prompt an error message indicating that the user is not logged in. I have tried a lot but it is not working as I expect. I think the session code is not working. please help me to find out the problem.

This is my login button code:

```
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=e-learningsystem; uid=root; password=123;port=3307;");
        connection.Open();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT Password FROM student WHERE UserName='" + TextBox2.Text + "'", connection);
            // string password;
            password = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if ((TextBox1.Text == password) && (dr.HasRows))
            {
                Response.Redirect("1stTymStuCategorySelection.aspx");
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    UserInfo ui = new UserInfo(dr["UserName"].ToString(), dr["Password"].ToString(), dr["Name"].ToString());
                    Session["loggedUser"] = ui;
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('INVALID Username and Password, Try Again!')</script>");
                // Session.Clear();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        TextBox2.Text = "";
        TextBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

This is my userInfo class code:

```
    public class UserInfo
{
    private string _UserName;
    private string _Password;
    private string _Name;

    public UserInfo(string UserName, string Password, string Name)
    {
        _UserName = UserName;
        _Password = Password;
        _Name = Name;
    }
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
    }
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _Password; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }

}
```

This is where the link hyperlink selection is done:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["loggedUser"] != null)
        {
            HyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "Year1Sem1Sub1.aspx";
        }
        else
        {
            HyperLink1.Visible = false;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug the page_load? what is the output you see after that conditional code is executed?

Comment: According to above code the link is disappeared

Comment: Why do you have that Response.Redirect code after you check the password? move that after you populate the session!
rather move it after the `connection.close()`

Comment: If I do so, it redirecting the page itself without doing anything...

Comment: Don't swallow the exception, at least set a break point in the catch, and do as Nilesh suggested.

Comment: The code has several major flaws:  
#1: You seem to be storing plain text passwords - passwords should be stored in a non-reversible format.
#2 You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  
#3 You have an empty catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are redirecting to another page before setting the `Session` value, thus `Session` is always `null`.

This code is the problem:

```
if ((TextBox1.Text == password) && (dr.HasRows))
{
    Response.Redirect("1stTymStuCategorySelection.aspx");
```

Move this `Response.Redirect` further down in the code logic (i.e. after you set the `Session` value).

Comment: If I write redirect code after connection.close , it redirecting the page itself without doing anything...

Comment: The connection has nothing to do with `Response.Redirect`, could you post your updated code with the redirect moved down below the `Session` value being set? By the way, you are mixing too many things together in this click event handler, you should break out the logic to check values in the database and then redirect based upon whether that was successful or not.